# Java hashCode for similar classes

Tags: java, hashcode

I have two similar classes, each with a single field of the same type.

```
class Fruit {
    private final String name;
}

class Vegetable {
    private final String name;
}
```

I'd like to implement `hashCode()` for each. My problem is that in my case, collisions between names are somewhat more possible than with "apple" and "carrot," and they both might be in the same Map/Set. I'm wondering what's the most clear way of implementing hashCode to handle this.

So far, I've considered `Objects.hash(this.getClass(), name)`, `Objects.hash(<some int unique to this class>, name)`. I like the first just because it's a bit more self-documenting and robust than the second, but it's not a pattern I've seen in the wild. I also considered `<some prime int unique to this class> * Objects.hashCode(name)`, but that felt fragile, especially if a new field gets added.

Comment: Is there a reason you're worried about hash collisions?

Comment: So to clarify, you're using something like a `HashSet` or `HashMap` (something that relies of `hashCode`) that contains both of those types?

Comment: Objects with the same hash code can be in the same set/map. The set/map uses equals for objects with the same hash code to find out if it's the same object

Comment: `hashCode` is used to determine if objects *aren't* equal (objects with different hash codes aren't equal; objects with equal hash codes *might be* equal); `equals` is used to determine if they *are* equal.

Comment: You would only get a collision if the Fruit and Vegetable has the same name. Can you give an example of the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Kayaman my objects are somewhat likely to share names. That's the only reason.

Comment: That's not really a reason. That's the cause. If they share names and your `hashCode()` is based only on the name, then identical names have same hashcodes. But is there a (good) reason you need to avoid that?

Comment: Re "but it's not a pattern I've seen in the wild" -- that may in part be because your use case is uncommon. You may want to consider other ways of modeling this data. Presumably, Fruit and Vegetable share some common interface (otherwise you'll need to type your set as `<Object>`, which is too permissive). If so, presumably that common class has all the fruit/veggie methods you need. So maybe just have one class, and an enum that says whether it's a fruit or veggie? A visitor pattern can help handle fruits and veggies in a type-safe way. That may not work for you, but it's worth considering.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 2 classes extend a common parent class, I solved this by adding a second field that would tell the instances of two different classes apart. This may be regarded as just another way of using the class name suggested by [David Ehrmann](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42330489/7249306) in his question. But in my case using an additional field looks more appropriate than using a class name. So here's my abstract parent class:

```
public abstract class NationalDish {
    public String dishName;
    public String country;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(country, dishName);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof NationalDish)) {
            return false;
        }
        NationalDish other = (NationalDish) obj;
        return Objects.equals(dishName, other.dishName) 
            && Objects.equals(country, other.country);
    }
}
```

Note how having the fields in the parent class allows to define equals() and hash code() in that same class and keep child classes to the minimum:

```
public class EnglishDish extends NationalDish {
    public EnglishDish(String dishName) {
        this.dishName = dishName;
        this.country = "England";
    }
}

public class AmericanDish extends NationalDish {
    public AmericanDish(String dishName) {
        this.dishName = dishName;
        this.country = "USA";
    }
}
```

Now, with country names (or plant types like in the question) in place we can have same name instances which will look different to Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NationalDish englishChips = new EnglishDish("Chips");
    NationalDish americanChips = new AmericanDish("Chips");
    System.out.println(englishChips.equals(americanChips)); // false
}
```